# How to style blockquote + cite to look like form fieldset + legend?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style a `blockquote` and child `cite` elements to replicate the appearance of a `fieldset` and `legend` element, where there is a border around the fieldset, and the legend label is inset in the top of the border -- if you've seen a fieldset you'll know what I mean.

I have a solution in which I give the `cite` a background-color, but this will only work when placed on a similar colored background. **I need a solution that will work on all backgrounds, bg images, etc. in IE8+**

Assume the following markup (cannot be changed from this. no additional elements allowed):

```
  <blockquote class="quote">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas rem, animi 
      facere illum deserunt nam ipsa, et sapiente quisquam sed repudiandae aliquam 
      delectus. Reiciendis repellat illo, et natus earum odit!
      <cite class="attribution">Mr. Jefferson</cite>
  </blockquote>
```

CSS I have so far:

```
.quote {
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}
.attribution {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 1rem;
  margin-top: -0.65rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  background: white; /* this works, but breaks if the background isn't white. I need a solution that works for all possible page bg colors */

}
```

This is what I have so far: http://jsbin.com/viqegerivi/edit?html,css,output

Comment: There is no CSS for "inherit background-color from parent, unless parent has `transparent`, in which case inherit recursively from its parent", so I'm afraid you have to use Javascript to do that.

Comment: @MrLister That's not what I'm asking. I want to just make it transparent. The background color technique is just a hack. It should replicate the behavior of the fieldset/legend. using background color is just the closest I could get, I specifically dont want to use a bg color.

Comment: But the problem is that when you use transparent, the border of the parent is visible behind the text. You will need a background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to admit, I enjoyed this one. Used absolutely positioned `:before`s and `:after`s, didn't touch your `HTML` markup but, as expected, went wild on CSS. Cheers!

```css
fieldset {
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}
legend {
  font-style: italic;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}
.quote {
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
  padding: 2.6rem calc(2rem + 6px) 1rem;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
.quote:before,
.quote:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  width: 4px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 1rem;
}
.quote:after {
  left: 0;
}
.quote:before {
  right: 0;
}
.attribution {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 2.4rem;
  margin-top: .35rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  background: transparent;
}
.attribution:before,
.attribution:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  bottom: calc(50% - 1px);
  height: 4px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100vw;
}
.attribution:before {
  right: 100%;
}
.attribution:after {
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>Desired Look:</p>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Mr. Jefferson</legend>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas rem, animi facere illum deserunt nam ipsa, et sapiente quisquam sed repudiandae aliquam delectus. Reiciendis repellat illo, et natus earum odit!
</fieldset>

<p>What I currently have:</p>
<blockquote class="quote">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas rem, animi facere illum deserunt nam ipsa, et sapiente quisquam sed repudiandae aliquam delectus. Reiciendis repellat illo, et natus earum odit!
  <cite class="attribution">Mr. Jefferson</cite>
</blockquote>
```

---

EDIT: As Mr Lister spotted, there is a differece between this and the fieldbox title model: the background of the blockquote runs **above** (what looks like) `top border`.

I personally don't consider it a significant problem as

1. it can be easily overcome by adding an extra wrapper for background-clipping, so it's achievable, but requires a slightly more complex markup.
2. I don't think many will use this model with a background color that is different from that of the page. My personal oppinion is that this model looks best when used with transparent background (that's why we interrupt the line, right?).

Also, the intial challenge I set for myself was to achieve the effect without touching the markup.

Comment: amazing! I wasn't sure this could be done. Star to you, CSS Ninja. :)

Comment: Very nice. +1. There is, however, a slight difference between the fieldset and the blockquote if you give them background colors. See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/efL2ehtu/). (The blockquote background extends above its border.)

Answer (score 1):

I tried this out, works well:

```
html {background:blue}
fieldset {
  border: 4px solid black;
      padding: 1rem 2rem;
}
legend {
  font-style: italic;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}


.quote {
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 1rem;
  width:auto;
  margin:0;
  position: relative;
}
.attribution {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 1rem;
  margin-top: -0.65rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  background:blue

}
```

Comment: You missed this part of the question: *"I have a solution in which I give the cite a background-color, but this will only work when placed on a similar colored background. I need a solution that will work on all backgrounds, bg images, etc. in IE8+"*

Comment: I did not account for images, right.
I did adjust the padding.